# Deserializar json que contiene una lista de objetos de diferente tipo

Tags: java, json, spring

Estoy atacando a un servicio REST utilizando `RestTemplate` de `Spring`.
La respuesta de este servicio es un `JSON` con un formato parecido al siguiente:

```
{
  "name": "miNombre",
  "options": [
    {
      "type": "a",
      "a": ["Test", "Test"]
    },
    {
      "type": "b",
      "b": ["Test", "Test"]
    },
    {
      "type": "c",
      "c": [
        {
          "d": "Test",
          "e": ["Test", "Test"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Como podemos observar la propiedad `options` es una lista con diferentes tipos de objetos.

El primer intento para **deserializar** este json fue crear una clase `Padre` para los tres posibles objetos en la lista y una clase por cada tipo de elemento en la lista que extienda esta clase Padre, algo como esto:

```
// Por simplicidad la llamaré clase ABC ya que es superclase de las otras
// Omito getters/setters para que sea más entendible
public class ABC {
  private String type;
}

public class A extends ABC {
  private ArrayList<String> a;
}

public class B extends ABC {
  private ArrayList<String> b;
}

public class C extends ABC {
  private ArrayList<DE> c;
}

public class DE {
  private String d;
  private ArrayList<String> d;
}

// Clase contenedora del objeto de la respuesta
public class Response {
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<ABC> options;
  private ArrayList<? extends ABC> options; // También he probado con genéricos sin suerte
}
```

La forma en la que uso RestTemplate es la siguiente:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> result = 
restTemplate.exchange("UnaURL", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Response.class);
```

El problema de esto es que los objetos de la lista una vez serializados solo contienen la propiedad común type.

Una solución (muy fea) que he conseguido es usar una clase que contenga todas las propiedades de los tres objetos:

```
public class ABCFeo {
  private String type;
  private ArrayList<String> a;
  private ArrayList<String> b;
  private ArrayList<DE> c;
}
```

Esta solución tendrá valores nulos. Por ejemplo, si es de tipo c, a y b serán null.

Otra solución que he probado es usar Object:

```
public class Response {
  private String name;
  private ArrayList<Object> options;
}
```

Pero no sé si es lo más correcto.

En principio busco alguna otra forma útil de almacenar en una lista estos diferentes tipos de objetos y que no falle al deserializar correctamente usando RestTemplate. ¿Es posible?

Comment: Lo 1º que hay que preguntar es si el WS depende de ti, por si puedes modificar la estructura del JSON si hiciera falta. Si lo pasas por [`jsonutils`](https://jsonutils.com), esto es lo que arroja. `public class C
{
    public String d;
    public List<String> e;
}

public class Option
{
    public String type;
    public List<String> a;
    public List<String> b;
    public List<C> c;
}

public class ABC
{
    public String name;
    public List<Option> options;
}` Si piensas usar Gson, esta sería la forma para mapear tu JSON a tu modelo de datos.

Comment: El resultado de `jsonutils` revela por tanto **el estado real de tu JSON**. Por ejemplo, se ve claramente que no hay una `class A` o una `class B`, porque en los `type a` y `type b` no hay dentro objetos JSON anidados. El problema, si quieres deserializar, es que no conviene forzar el modelo de datos haciéndolo incoherente con el JSON, sino todo lo contrario, el JSON debe representar de una manera justa el modelo de datos que necesitas en tu aplicación. Así, al hacer uso de librerías como Gson, o si tuvieras que trasladarlo a otras plataformas, podrás recibir el JSON y mapearlo a la clase.

Comment: Gracias por responder @A.Cedano! Se me pasó ponerlo en la pregunta. No tengo acceso al WS que comento para poder modificarlo. Por poner un poco de contexto, esta lista, contiene diferentes tipos de `grants` y cada tipo de Grant tiene su estructura. Lo que me comentas sería muy similar a lo que probé con el ejemplo de `ABCFeo`. Realmente no creo que me haga falta mantener el tipado para los tres tipos de `grants`. Me surge ahora la duda si lo pudiera almacenar en otro tipo de estructura como HashMap en lugar de ir por la solución con clases (Si esto me va a ahorrar trabajo)

Comment: No es tu modelo `ABCFeo` es que es *feo*. Es la estructura que estás consumiendo la que es *fea*, en el sentido de que no tiene estructuras homogéneas. Como quiera quedan muchas preguntas abiertas: ¿en el JSON sólo habrá tipos a, b y c con la misma estructura?¿o hay tipos c, d, z con no importa qué estructura? ¿o en algún caso un tipo `c` puede venir como el tipo `a` y viceversa? Responder a esas preguntas es esencial para entonces pasar a modelar los datos. No olvides lo que significa el concepto mismo de `clase`. Cuando modelas los datos tienes que estar seguro de que en los datos no ...

Comment: ... se te colará un marciano (un tipo de dato extraño al modelo que hará que la aplicación haga crash). Más aún si no controlas los datos que estás recibiendo. Sin esas garantías es imposible dar una respuesta definitiva al problema. Para mi un JSON debería representar fielmente un modelo de datos que es parte del funcionamiento de un programa, no una cosa dispar que trae no importa qué o cómo. O sea,  lo que se debe buscar es que con facilidad el JSON conecte con tu modelo de datos **en cualquier situación** y usar el modelo para simplificar cualquier tipo de requerimiento complicado.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir. El JSON que devuelve el servicio tiene la estructura que he comentado. En ese aspecto no estoy preocupado. La única peculiaridad es que la lista puede contener solo uno de los tipos, o dos o los tres a la vez.

Comment: Eso no sería problema, pues a lo sumo lo resolverías con una anotación `@Nullable` en el modelo y en el código mediante previa verificación de que ese dato vino en el JSON

Comment: @A.Cedano Al final me he decantado por el `ABCFeo`. Creo que es la mejor opción en relación funcionalidad/tiempo de desarrollo. También barajé la posibilidad de declarar la lista como `List<JsonObject>`.

Answer (score 1):

No las puedo probar, pero se me ocurren dos soluciones:

### Varios setters para un mismo atributo:

```
public class ABC {
  private String type;
  private List<String> lista;

  @JsonSetter("a")
  public void setA(List<String> lista) {
    this.lista=lista;
  }


  @JsonSetter("b")
  public void setB(List<String> lista) {
    this.lista=lista;
  }

  @JsonSetter("c")
  public void setC(List<String> lista) {
    this.lista=lista;
  }
}
```

### Marcar un atributo con varios nombres

**Nota**: No estoy seguro si esto (poner varias anotaciones) funcionará, lo he usado sólo para renombrar atributos, con una única anotación por atributo:

```
public class ABC {
  private String type;
  private List<String> lista;

  @JsonProperty("a")
  @JsonProperty("b")
  @JsonProperty("c")
  public void setLista(List<String> lista) {
    this.lista=lista;
  }
}
```

Comment: mm tiene muy buena pinta la primera solución, aunque no encaja del todo con mi caso de uso ya que la propiedad C sería de tipo `ArrayList<DE>`.

Comment: Como he puesto en un comentario no me importa perder los tipos. Es decir, se me ocurre almacenar la lista como `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`, aunque no he probado si se deserializa correctamente y no sé si sería una buena solución.

Comment: Una solución mucho más compleja sería crear una deserializador de JSON nuevo y decirle a RestTemplate que lo use en lugar del estándar, pero es bastante más trabajo

Comment: He visto algún ejemplo creando un `Custom MessageConverter`, pero como comentas me llevaría más trabajo. Esperaba que hubiera alguna solución más fácil. Lo tomo como sugerencia. En cuanto pueda probar comento como ha ido. Muchas gracias por las sugerencias! =)